# What does pasv_enable and related fields mean in vsftpd.conf

Tags: ssh, ftp, sftp, vsftpd

I just installed vsftpd according to [these directions](http://www.liquidweb.com/kb/how-to-install-and-configure-vsftpd-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts/).

I am trying to get ftp working on my Ubuntu box that is using Amazon AWS.  When I first tried this directions, it did not work.  I was trying to connect via FileZilla and Winscp from my windows machine to my Ubuntu server.

When it failed, I tried adding [these options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4723023/vsftpd-error-listing-directories) to my `/etc/vsftpd.conf` file.  Specifically:

```
pasv_enable=YES
pasv_min_port=64000
pasv_max_port=64321
port_enable=YES
pasv_address=<your-publicly-resolvable-host-name>
pasv_addr_resolve=YES <or> NO
```

This did not help.  Finally, what did work was switching winSCP into "Active Mode".  My question is: What do those different parameters mean?  I am assuming that in is to enable passive mode, and to help guide the ports used for passive mode, but I am not sure what `port_enable` `pasv_address` and `pasv_addr_resolve` do.

Also, now that I am using active mode, do I need to have any of those entries? Thank you

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is (obviously) manual page for [`vsftpd.conf`](http://vsftpd.beasts.org/vsftpd_conf.html), which is always a good place to start.

TLDR version: They should be needed only for passive mode of FTP.

> **pasv_enable**
>
> Set to NO if you want to disallow the PASV method of obtaining a data connection.
>
> Default: YES

---

> **pasv_address**
>
> Use this option to override the IP address that vsftpd will advertise in response to the PASV command. Provide a numeric IP address, unless `pasv_addr_resolve` is enabled, in which case you can provide a hostname which will be DNS resolved for you at startup.
>
> Default: (none - the address is taken from the incoming connected socket)

---

> **pasv_addr_resolve**
>
> Set to YES if you want to use a hostname (as opposed to IP address) in the `pasv_address` option.
>
> Default: NO